# Unifrom sampling

Tags: statistics, self-learning

I came across the term "uniform subsampling" in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06476) (page 5). I tried to understand the meaning of it but got no luck.

Here is the extract from the paper:

> A naive approach to constructing coresets is based on uniform
> subsampling of the data. For the sake of simplicity, consider a data
> set $\mathcal{X}$ with constant weights $\mu_{\mathcal{X}}(x) = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{X}|}$ . For any query $Q \in \mathcal{Q}$, the
> cost function in (2.1) may be rewritten as
> $$
> \operatorname{cost}(\mathcal{X}, Q)=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{X}|} f_{Q}(x)=\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f_{Q}(x)\right]
> $$
> where $x \in X$ is drawn uniformly at random.
> Let the set C consist of m points sampled uniformly at random from $\mathcal{X}$
> and set $\mu_C(x) = \frac{1}{m}$.

The closes I came across is the answer from [here](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3879#:%7E:text=Definition%3A,with%20a%20uniform%20sampling%20fraction.). The definition is:

> If a sample is selected from a population which has been grouped into
> strata, in such a way that the number of units selected from each
> stratum is proportional to the total number of units in that stratum,
> the sample is said to have been selected with a uniform sampling
> fraction.

I would really appreciate it if someone can explain this concept to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote the sentence you're having trouble with instead of asking us to download the paper and read through it.

Comment: @saulspatz, sorry about that. I assumed that it was a well-known term that mathematicians knew. I edited the question as you requested. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at Equation 2.3 of that paper, I believe they are describing uniform subsampling. You just draw samples from a data set with uniform probability. This will non-parametrically approximate the underlying distribution, and is often called boostrapping. In this case (Eq.2.3), they're using bootstrapping to approximate the expected value.

See the wiki entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)

In python, you can get a uniform sample easily using libraries like numpy:

```
from numpy.random import uniform, randint

num_data = 100

//
// Get 10 samples in the range 0 to num_data
p = uniform(size=(10,)) * num_data
print(p.astype(int))

//
// Alternatively, you can just uniformly sample 
// random integers which is probably easier 
p = randint(low=0, high=num_data, size=(10,))
print(p)

//
// Now if you have data... you just get it like this
pretend_this_is_data = arange(100)
uniform_data_sample = pretend_this_is_data[p]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. Could you point me in the direction of how to sample from a uniform distribution? It seems like random sampling for me

Comment: It is random sampling. Most programming languages have a library that includes this, but if you want to write your own random number generator, that's another thing altogether. What language are you using?

Comment: I appreciate your response! I was feeling stupid for not getting it. I can use R or Python. I wanted to understand the math behind it. So basically it's random sampling from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The idea is that you sample from the interval [0,N], where N is the number of datapoints that you have. If you get a a number in the range [i, i+1), then you use the i-th data point. Do this until you have sampled enough data points to make up your coreset. I put the python for uniform sampling in the answer. Multiply it by N to get the range you want.

Comment: wow! thanks mate. Really appreciate your response. I saw your code and it's really helpful! You the best!